# Application pool recycling takes high time

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc, application-pools

We have problem with Application pool recycling process. We have our production site with hosted in IIS version 10. We have used separate application pool for our production site. This application pool getting recycling every 1740  mins by default. The problem is once recycle process started our application is not responding. Seems its usual thing it takes some time to start with new process. But our case it takes around 15-20 mins to getting the palliation up or recycle process to complete. After 20 mins only our site coming up. Seems this time interval is unusual. How to troubleshoot this problem? Is there any problem in application level or server or application pool configuration level? Please help to identify the cause, we couldn’t find the solution to address our site down problem.

Thanks,
Karthik.

Comment: An app pool only has a small amount of time to start up and declare itself “healthy”.  IIS then sends all new requests to the new one and the old one is shutdown gracefully.  If it’s still running after 15-20 minutes then it’s not the app pool but the application running within it.  What is your application doing during startup?

Comment: @GregW: We are just hitting DB to get some global values and assign that to static variable, then usual routing and bundling config code.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is it's most likely not the application pool having issues starting up.  IIS kills the failed app pool and tries x more times to start one.  If it doesn't then it stops the app pool and waits for administrative action.  If it's still running after a few minutes, then my guess is the app pool itself is healthy but the custom app is having issues of some kind.  Do you have any logging/tracing to measure how long each step is taking?

Comment: No, we don't have any logging, could you tell any steps to logging/tracing application pool recycling process?

Answer (score 0):

On Advantage Settings from the pool, try to configure the *Idle Time-out* (by default is 20 minutes), when you have 20 minutes without any traffic then the app pool will terminate/Recycling.